# ScrollTrigger Animation with gsap is not responsive on resize width

Tags: resize, gsap, scrolltrigger

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container" style="height: 100vh; background-color: grey"></div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.10.2/gsap.min.js"> 
    </script>
    <script 
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.10.2/ScrollTrigger.min.js"> 
    </script>
<script>
    gsap.registerPlugin('ScrollTrigger');
    let tl = gsap.timeline({
        scrollTrigger: {
        trigger: '.container',
        pin: true,
        start: 'bottom bottom',
        end: 'bottom start',
        markers: true,
        },
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I scroll to middle and resize width, animation is distorted, markers are not at
right place, white area is seen.

Comment: After resize try `ScrollTrigger.refresh()`

Comment: New GSAP option (Works like magic): https://greensock.com/docs/v3/GSAP/gsap.matchMedia()